# Hundred of Thousands of database records and how to safely delete them?

Tags: commerce

Hi
I've been asked to work on a Drupal commerce site and I'm not very familiar with this module.

The idea is to use an existing database and export it to 'quickstart' a new site.
I'm to keep all the products but delete all the customers and transactions data.
But when I look at the DB of the existing site it's packed with hundreds of thousands of stuff that I don't understand.

The product catalog only includes 50 or 80 products or so but in the database I see an incredible number of rows in some of the table and I don't know how I can safely remove all this data without breaking the database. Here is what I see in php/myadmin:

```
field_revision_commerce_unit_price   ~210,219 InnoDB    utf8_general_ci 129.7 MiB   -
field_revision_commerce_total    ~211,353    InnoDB utf8_general_ci 128.7 MiB   -
field_data_commerce_unit_price   ~210,696    InnoDB utf8_general_ci 128.6 MiB   -
field_data_commerce_total    ~209,449    InnoDB utf8_general_ci 127.6 MiB   -
field_revision_commerce_order_total ~210,849 InnoDB utf8_general_ci 125.5 MiB   -
field_data_commerce_order_total  ~210,129    InnoDB utf8_general_ci 119.5 MiB   -
field_revision_commerce_product  ~210,384    InnoDB utf8_general_ci 82.5 MiB    -
field_data_commerce_product  ~210,384    InnoDB utf8_general_ci 81.4 MiB    -
field_revision_commerce_line_items ~211,257  InnoDB utf8_general_ci 81.4 MiB    -
field_revision_commerce_display_path ~210,521 InnoDB    utf8_general_ci 77.5 MiB    -
field_data_commerce_display_path ~210,521    InnoDB utf8_general_ci 76.4 MiB    -
field_data_commerce_line_items   ~210,393 InnoDB    utf8_general_ci 75.4 MiB    -
field_revision_field_dept_date   ~210,384    InnoDB utf8_general_ci 69 MiB  -
field_data_field_dept_date ~210,384 InnoDB  utf8_general_ci 68.9 MiB    -
commerce_line_item   ~211,134 InnoDB    utf8_general_ci 34.6 MiB    -
commerce_order   ~210,442 InnoDB    utf8_general_ci 34.1 MiB    -
commerce_order_revision ~212,036 InnoDB utf8_general_ci 26.1 MiB    -
```

I'm really lost here isn't there a quicker way to delete all the unnecessary data while keeping the product catalog intact?
Thanks

Comment: Does this site (or does Commerce in general) save off a new revision for every node / entity edit?

Comment: @MPD Only if you set it up that way. I believe the revision checkbox is checked by default when creating a new product type though

Answer (score 2):

Forget about accessing the database manually, you will just break things.

For mass-deletion create a [VBO](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)-based view.

Same thing for export, you will want to export whole entities, not tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view with all your nodes you want to delete, be careful to select only good node types

Browse the view result in a custom module. First, do it safely without node_delete_multiple() ! Do it on a backuped DB !

```
$view = views_get_view ('your_view_name');
$view->execute();

if(count($view->result) > 0){
  //dpr($result); //print the result before to delete
  $deletelist = array();
  foreach($view->result as $result){
    $deletelist[] = $result->nid; // check this is the right fieldname in your view result
  }
  //node_delete_multiple($deletelist); // only when you are sure !
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a closer look at that , but I need to know what I can safely delete to preserve my products so that only the customer profiles and information related to previous orders and shopping carts get deleted. Also I have to process hundreds of thousands of records. I don't know how the SQL server and APACHE will like this if it's not done batch by batch...